# Android Studio, Desktop.ini, The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android, powershell, error-handling, desktop.ini

My android studio project has files named 'desktop.ini'. Inside they all contain-

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
InfoTip=This folder is shared online.
IconFile=C:\Program Files\Google\Drive\googledrivesync.exe
IconIndex=16
```

When I try to run my project I get the error
[image]

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Remove those files from your `res/` directory tree. Android apps do not use `.ini` files as resources.

Comment: @CommonsWare That why I using linux)